# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Tags: android, flutter, dart, syncfusion

I'm trying to save a pdf on my device , but i got this error

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/esofos.health/files'/test.pdf

this is the function that generate the document

```
_generatepdf() async {

//Get external storage directory
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
//Get directory path
final path = directory;
// Create a new PDF document.
final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
// Add a PDF page and draw text.
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
    'Hello World!', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 12),
    brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)),
    bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 150, 20));

// Save the document.
print(path);
File('$path/test.pdf').writeAsBytes(document.save());
// Dispose the document.
document.dispose();

};
```

Comment: It is hard to believe that getExternalStorageDirectory(); would deliver that path. But then i do not know Flutter...

Comment: `final path = directory;` Why another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Directory` [path](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-io/Directory/path.html) property not string representation of class. Something like this:

```
File('${directory.path}/test.pdf').writeAsBytes(document.save());
```

Answer (score 0):

If is not an app that needs the to access the device external storage (e.g antivirus app) and you want to download a file in Flutter, you might just use the package [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to use your app specific directory provider by android during installation. use this to download file

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL!));
final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();//use this please instead of  getExternalStorageDirectory
File file = File(appDir.path + '/${filename}');
try {
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  print('success');
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When checking the provided code snippet, the directory path was not type casted properly. We request you to change the below code to save and open the pdf file properly.

```
final path = directory!.path;
```

Please refer to the below documentation link,

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/getting-started#save-and-open-a-pdf-document-in-mobile